# How can I pause, resume or control the speed of facebook-pop animation?

Tags: ios, animation, facebook-pop

Before using facebook-pop, I have used core animation. So I can pause, resume or control the speed of animation by changing the speed of the CALayer.

Now I have used facebook-pop in some situation and found it very powerful. I want to use facebook-pop to replace my legacy animation code. But when I changed the layer speed to 0, the animation won't pause.

Please tell me how can I pause, resume or control the speed of facebook-pop animation? I have googled a lot but couldn't found any hint.

Edit 1:
Maybe I can remove old animation to implement pausing, add new animation to implement resuming and update duration to implement changing speed. At this point, pop is not as convenient as core animation.

Answer (score 0):

`POPAnimation` has a `paused` property that will pause an animation.

In terms of speed it depends on the animation. `POPSpringAnimation` has a speed property, as you note for other types you can change the `duration`.